# Unknown command: shell_plus and --settings

Tags: python, django, django-shell

I try to run some

```
python manage.py shell_plus --notebook --settings=my_app.settings.andi
```

But it fails with error:

```
Unknown command: 'shell_plus'
Type 'manage.py help' for usage.
```

I have ipython and shell_plus installed (from my pip freeze)

```
django-shell-plus==1.1.5
ipython==1.2.1
```

How to deal with it?

Comment: Have you added `shell_plus` to your `INSTALLED_APPS`?

Comment: @neoascetic Is there `--notebook` ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

According to [documentation](https://bitbucket.org/schinckel/django-shell/), you need to call it as `./manage.py shell+`.

Probably you've mixed up this command with [`shell_plus`](https://github.com/django-extensions/django-extensions/blob/master/docs/shell_plus.rst) from [`django-extensions`](https://github.com/django-extensions/django-extensions)?

Comment: Link is outdated

Answer (score 49):

1. Make sure you have installed `django-extensions`.

   `pip install django-extensions`
2. Add `django_extensions` (note the underscore between) to the `INSTALLED_APPS` list in `settings.py` file of your project.

Comment: This was very useful. Just to clarify, in step (2) it should added be to `INSTALLED_APPS` (spelling) within `settings.py` (or whatever python file you use for settings).